# WPF MVVMLight TabControl SelectedIndex doesn't change TabItem

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm-light, tabcontrol

I have many TabItem in my TabControl.
I'm binding my TabControl with SelectedIndex property :

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
    <TabItem Header="TabItem1">
        ...
    </TabItem>
    ...
</TabControl>
```

I want to come back on first TabItem when I select the third TabItem. So I'm trying to change the setter of property :

```
private int _selectedIndex;
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return _selectedIndex; }

    set
    {
        if (value == 2)
            value = 0;

        Set(ref _selectedIndex, value);
    }
}
```

But the TabItem remains on the third TabItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can honestly say I don't know why this works. But adding "IsAsync=True" fixed this for me.

I guess it could be that the binding is taking too long. As this MSDN article suggests
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync(v=vs.110).aspx

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, IsAsync=True}">
```